# Unable to read data from Bag in Pig Script/

Tags: apache-pig

Can you please let me know if I have {',') delimited field and having Bag Data ,How to read. I am getting below error.

```
Input Data.
Jorge Posada Yankees|{(Catcher),(Designated_hitter)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]
Landon Powell Oakland|{(Catcher),(First_baseman)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]
Martin Prado Atlanta|{(Second_baseman),(Infielder),(Left_fielder)},[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]

bfile= LOAD '/home/cloudera/basketball.txt' using PigStorage('|')as(name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:(p:chararray)},bat:map[]);

grunt> players = load 'basketball.txt' using PigStorage('|')as (name:chararray, team:chararray,position:bag{t:(p:chararray)}, bat:map[]);
2014-11-13 04:49:48,144 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 27, column 117>  mismatched input ';' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1415835089181.log
```

Sanjeeb

Comment: I didnt see the delimiter '|' between name and the team(ie, Jorge Posada Yankees), its a blank space is this expected?. In the given input the third line is ',' as  delimiter between position and bat. is this expected?

Comment: Hey,I have updated the data.Sorry about that. bfile= LOAD '/home/cloudera/basketball.txt' using PigStorage('|')as(name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:(p:chararray)},bat:map[]);Jorge Posada |Yankees|{(Catcher),(Designated_hitter)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher),(First_baseman)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]
Martin Prado |Atlanta|{(Second_baseman),(Infielder),(Left_fielder)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]

Comment: i am able to load and access the above data successfully. Its looks like the error is at line no 27 in your script . ERROR 1200: <line 27, column 117> . Can you paste the 27th line of you pig script?

Comment: I am usnig only one linie to read the file.I dont know why it is pointing to 27th line. Can you help me to understand the regex operaton or usage with some sample example.I have seen in the forum u have written lot about this..Pls explaini with some sample example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above input, regex is not required, you can access all the values using the existing schema itself.

**input.txt**

```
Jorge Posada |Yankees|{(Catcher),(Designated_hitter)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher),(First_baseman)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]
Martin Prado |Atlanta|{(Second_baseman),(Infielder),(Left_fielder)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]
```

**Pigscript:**

```
bfile= LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:(p:chararray)},bat:map[]);

--Print the name and team
B = FOREACH bfile GENERATE name,team;
--DUMP B;

--Print the player and his position
C = FOREACH bfile GENERATE name,pos.(p);
--DUMP C;

--Print the player and  key/value of games and hit_by_pitch
D = FOREACH bfile GENERATE name,bat#'games',bat#'hit_by_pitch';
--DUMP D;
```

**Output of DUMP B:**

```
(Jorge Posada ,Yankees)
(Landon Powell ,Oakland)
(Martin Prado ,Atlanta)
```

**Output Of DUMP C:**

```
(Jorge Posada ,{(Catcher),(Designated_hitter)})
(Landon Powell ,{(Catcher),(First_baseman)})
(Martin Prado ,{(Second_baseman),(Infielder),(Left_fielder)})
```

**Output Of DUMP D:**

```
(Jorge Posada ,1594,65)
(Landon Powell ,26,)
(Martin Prado ,258,3)
```

In the bag, if you need multiple fields then declare and access like this

```
pos:bag{t:(p:chararray,q:charrarray)}
FOREACH bfile GENERATE name,pos.(p,q);
```

Comment: Thanks Siva..I know for this Regex is not required..But I just want to use for some data in my POC.But I really don't understand the concept.Can yo bit elaborate here..Pls.

Comment: Thanks a lot Siva..Its working perfect...But Pls explain me about the Regex one.

Comment: Cool.Please mark this question as answered. Sure what you want from regex?. can you tell me what exactly you need?

Comment: siva where to do that..Pls let me know ...Regarding regex extract,You have any doc or link to understand basics..I don't know any thing about that..

Comment: click the tick mark button in the left side of answer section. For regex i usually use http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and http://regex101.com/ to simulate the regex